# Storing a variable in an array (that functions as a value in an object) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a simple function that checks if the username already exists in the array of objects, in case it does, it should save new time in an array in format { username: username, time: [firsttime, secondtime, etc] }. The code itself is rough, but the problem is that if the username doesn't exist (and the array is not empty, so there are some other usernames saved already), the function saves the time two times, if I try the same username, I get one more object with double time.

```js
let array = []
const userName = prompt("username")
const userTime = prompt("points")
if (array.length > 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].username === userName) {
      array[i].time.push(userTime)
    } else {
      const thisTime = {
        username: userName,
        time: [userTime]
      }
      array.push(thisTime)
    }
  }
} else {
  const firstTime = {
    username: userName,
    time: [userTime]
  }
  array.push(firstTime)
  console.log(array)
}
```

So on the first round i get [{username: "maria", time: Array(1)}]

On the second round with another username [{username: "maria", time: Array(1)}, {username: "ariana", time: Array(2) e.g. [14,14] (*should be only 1 value*)}]

*The code was edited according to the rules, so actual username and time are added in course of the game.*

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with relevant code to make a [mcve]

Comment: Should I rewrite the code with different variables?

Comment: No, you need to update to a working example with a set of example points

Comment: It would be too much code to write the whole working version, so I have updated to more or less working one. But I already got an answer anyway, thank you.

Comment: That is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with a more efficient and less error prone way:

```
// look for the index in the array
const pointIndex = this.points.findIndex(point => point.username === this.username);

if(pointIndex > -1){ // if found, push the time
  this.points[pointIndex].time.push(this.globalTime);
}
else { // push a new point otherwise
  const thisTime = {
    username: this.username,
    time: [this.globalTime]
  }
  this.points.push(thisTime)
}
```